# Is there any thing similar to HAML in rails3?

Tags: ruby, plugins, haml, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a little tried with erb because of the <%=%>.

HAML is a proper option,just wondering if there is any like HAML or something even cooler or better?

It will be really helpful if you also attach the URL of thing you recommend.

Comment: HAML rocks and I have no idea why it's not the default in Rails 3.1

Comment: yes,I think it is great,It deserve to default in Rails3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there're a couple:

- http://www.hokstad.com/mini-reviews-of-19-ruby-template-engines.html
- https://github.com/stonean/slim
- https://github.com/defunkt/mustache

But personnaly, if I wouldn't want to use erb I would go with HAML (even though it's somewhat python-looking)